# Android Development Bluetooth Scan

Tags: java, android

I'm Trying to build an App that can scan all nearby Devices . My only problem is that it scan between `5-8` secs. Is there a way to scan for example every  or `2` seconds.

```
bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovering()
```

Receiver

```
if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
BluetoothDevice device = -intentData.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    if(device != null) {
       //code to push in listview
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can u please explain your question a bit?? can't understand what you want to achieve?? to check for available device every 2 seconds ?? or just for 2 second?

Comment: I want to heck for available device every 2 seconds.